# MySQL: how to quote or escape field names?

Tags: mysql

Recently I was given a MySQL DB that included a field named time-taken, which caused errors when used in a select because of the minus sign.

In this case I was able to rename the field, but for future reference how can field names be quoted or escaped in a MySQL query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the field in backticks.

```
SELECT * from `table` WHERE `int` = 0
```

Here's the [**reference page**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html).

Comment: That would be the one type of quote I didn't try :-)